# Bash tr sed / awk challenging script

Tags: bash, sed, html-table, tr, wc

A server provides a list of asset IDs separated by commas in square brackets after the date and colons :

```
20160420084726:-
20160420085418:[111783178, 111557953, 111646835, 111413356, 111412662, 105618372, 111413557]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085418:[111413432, 111633904, 111783198, 111792767, 111557948, 111413225, 111413281]
20160420085522:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
20160420090022:[111344871, 111394583, 111295547, 111379566, 111352520]
```

The format of the input log is:

```
timestamp:ads
```

Where: timestamp is in the format `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`, and ads is a comma separated list of ad asset IDs surrounded by square brackets, or - if no ads were returned.

The first part of the task is to write a script that outputs, for each ten minute slice of the day:

Count of IDs that were returned
Count of unique IDs that were returned
Script should support a command line parameter to select whether unique or total IDs should be given.
Example output using the above log excerpt (in total mode):

```
20160420084:0
20160420085:26
20160420090:5
```

And in unique count mode it would give:

```
20160420084:0
20160420085:19
20160420090:5
```

I have tried this:

```
awk -F '[,:]' '
                    {
                      key = substr($1,1,11)"0"
                      count[key] += ($2 == "-" ? 0 : NF-1)
                    } 
                    END {
                    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
                    for (key in count) print key, count[key]
                  }
                    ' $LOGFILENAME | grep $DATE;
```

However, many scenarios fail. For example this one:

log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sXFvLyCH8gZrXiqf095MubyP7-sLVUXt/view?usp=sharing

The first few lines of the results should be:

nonunique:

```
20160420000:1
20160420001:11
20160420002:13
20160420003:16
20160420004:3
20160420005:3
20160420010:6
```

unique:

```
20160420000:1
20160420001:5
20160420002:5
20160420003:5
20160420004:3
20160420005:3
20160420010:4
```

Help please `:s`

Comment: your script already returns true results even for the referenced link ( `20160420010:6` shouldn't return for the non-unique one, and your script does this, and return the other rows ).

Comment: This exact question was asked and answered a few days ago. If this is intended to be a followup question then don't delete the previous one as people will want to look at the answer you got to that to see in what way this is different and will want you to state those differences. Also you got an awk answer then and awk is the right tool for this (definitely not sed!) so, obviously, you should tag this with awk too. And again - tell us what this has to do with `html-table` which you keep tagging it with.